Update a document in MongoDB with a regular expression
In a Typescript source code on Nodejs using MongoClient, I need to search for a field ("provider", declared as a string) with a regular expression and then update that field:
 await updatePromise(
        metadata_collection,
        {
            provider: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${provider}$`, "i") },
            code
        },
        {
            $set:
                provider.toLowerCase() === "eurostat"
                    ? { ...allEurostatMetadata, provider }
                    : { ...metaData, provider }
        },
        true,
        migrationFlowsProxy
    );

The problem here is that I have the error
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ $regex: RegExp; }'.ts(2322)

apparently because the compiler treats "provider" as a regExpr in the set and not a string, as originally declared.
"updatePromise" is a wrapper for "updateMany":
function updatePromise<T>(
    collection: string,
    filter: Query<T>,
    updateParams: UpdateQuery<T>,
    upsert = false,
    proxy = _mongoProxy
): Promise<UpdateResult | Document>

I'm using (yes, the libraries are not up to date):
mongodb@4.16.0
typescript@4.5.5

